# Why does ConcurrentHashMap use a local variable `tab` to reference the table?

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

In `ConcurrentHashMap.putVal()` (JDK Version: 11; ConcurrentHashMap.java; line 1010)

```java
final V putVal(K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent) {
   if (key == null || value == null) throw new NullPointerException();
   int hash = spread(key.hashCode());
   int binCount = 0;
   for (Node<K,V>[] tab = table;;) {
       ...
   }
   addCount(1L, binCount);
   return null;
}
```

Why does it use the variable `tab` to reference the table?
Likewise in `ConcurrentHashMap.get()` (beginning on line 934)

```java
public V get(Object key) {
    Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> e, p; int n, eh; K ek;
    int h = spread(key.hashCode());
    if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 &&
        (e = tabAt(tab, (n - 1) & h)) != null) {
        if ((eh = e.hash) == h) {
            if ((ek = e.key) == key || (ek != null && key.equals(ek)))
                return e.val;
        }
        else if (eh < 0)
            return (p = e.find(h, key)) != null ? p.val : null;
        while ((e = e.next) != null) {
            if (e.hash == h &&
                ((ek = e.key) == key || (ek != null && key.equals(ek))))
                return e.val;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Is this in the source code for ConcurrentHashMap or is this in example code provided by somebody else?

Comment: Where did this come from? Please link to the source.

Comment: @NomadMaker yes this is in source code int JDK (version 11) ConcurrnentHashMap on the line 1014

Comment: @Thomas Kläger use new reference in stack frame can make getting table Object more faster?

Comment: Linking to the source code would be a convenience to the reader.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `table`, the instance it points to can change while working on it, which can lead to undefined behavior or exceptions. Thus, you need to "fixate" it locally and use that local variable.

I **assume** this is done to prevent undefined behavior if it is, which should not be done, used by two threads at once in write mode*. The instance at which `table` points to can change even in the not-concurrent HashMap.

An alternative to this would be using the keyword synchronized, but that reduces performance.

* You can read from a HashMap in multiple threads without issue if it is not getting manipulated while multiple threads hold it.

Comment: thank your anser. And could you give an example to illustrate more detailly ?

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to see why Java does this in `HashMap` where the `resize()` method sets `table = newTab`. Any method that was reading the `table` during a `resize()` operation would have the reference pulled out from under them and reassigned, which would cause unpredictable behavior.

`Volatile` could ensure a reading method is updated with the latest `table`; but that is not at all what we want. We want the reading method to continue uninterrupted with the values that were in the `table` when it began reading.

`Synchronized` could block reads and writes from happening simultaneously, but with a performance penalty. If we wanted that, we could revert to using `Hashtable`.

The same basic reasoning applies to `ConcurrentHashMap` and its more complicated `transfer()` method which also reassigns the `table` reference. The reference is copied into a local variable to avoid losing it during reassignment.

Comment: HashTable also uses this

Comment: ```java
public synchronized V get(Object key) {
    Entry<?,?> tab[] = table;
    int hash = key.hashCode();
    int index = (hash & 0x7FFFFFFF) % tab.length;
    for (Entry<?,?> e = tab[index] ; e != null ; e = e.next) {
        if ((e.hash == hash) && e.key.equals(key)) {
            return (V)e.value;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The `rehash()` method in `Hashtable` is in fact _not_ synchronized, so apparently it still has to protect against the same `table` reassignment.

Answer (score 0):

For the performance.using local variable in method is more effective than using global variable.
let's see th code block.

```
public class LocalFieldDemo {
  private String[] globalArr = new String[123];
  public void test() {
      String[] localArr = globalArr;
      for (int i = 0; i < 123; i++) {
          System.out.println(localArr[i]);
      }
  }
}
```

we see the bytecode

```
public void test();
  Code:
     0: aload_0
     1: getfield      #3                  // Field globalArr:[Ljava/lang/String;
     4: astore_1
     5: iconst_0
     6: istore_2
     7: iload_2
     8: bipush        123
    10: if_icmpge     28
    13: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    16: aload_1
    17: iload_2
    18: aaload
    19: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    22: iinc          2, 1
    25: goto          7
    28: return
```

---

and see the second code block:

```
public class InstanceFieldDemo {
  private String[] globalArr = new String[123];
  public void test() {
      for (int i = 0; i < 123; i++) {
          System.out.println(globalArr[i]);
      }
  }
}
```

the bytecode of this code block

```
public void test();
  Code:
     0: iconst_0
     1: istore_1
     2: iload_1
     3: bipush        123
     5: if_icmpge     26
     8: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    11: aload_0
    12: getfield      #3                  // Field globalArr:[Ljava/lang/String;
    15: iload_1
    16: aaload
    17: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    20: iinc          1, 1
    23: goto          2
    26: return
```

what the difference happen?
we can see, in the second bytecode

```
11: aload_0
12: getfield      #3                  // Field globalArr:[Ljava/lang/String;
```

but the first bytecode:

```
16: aload_1
```

if we get value by global variable, jvm must take the command aload_0 to get `this`,and get field `globalArr`. In the second code, we only use the one command `aload` to get the value. The second code block has better performance.